# Best way to search for R packages?

Tags: r, search

#### Related question

> [how to search for r materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102056/how-to-search-for-r-materials)

Part of the reason why the R community has been attracted to a tag based service like StackOverflow, I think, is that information on R is fundamentally difficult to find online.  Services like [RSeek](http://www.rseek.org/) have made this slightly less painful, however, I often find the search results scattered.

Specifically, I am often curious if R packages exist to meet a specific need I am facing.  RSeek is useful for finding package documentation, but not for discovering new packages---and the R package manager is even less useful.  As such, what are some best practices for searching for packages?  That is, when I realize I have a need that my current set of R packages will not meet, and before creating the functionality myself I would like to search for a package that will meet the need.  What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: I have to disagree with your duplicate assertion Dirk. That question is related to finding general R info. Drew asked about how to find the right package for a purpose. It's a nuance or a subset of the prior question, but more specific.

Comment: I concur - this isn't a duplicate; related, but not a duplicate

Comment: Warren, thanks for changing this to related not dupe.

Answer (score 26):

First, use `help.search()` or the shorthand `??`. This will search the help files of installed packages. I often find I have a package installed that does what I want; I just haven't used it before.

Next, use the `findFn` function in the `sos` package. This function searches the help pages of packages covered by the RSiteSearch archives (which includes all packages on CRAN). These are ordered based on a relevance score, so the top few packages on the list are probably the most useful.

To look even further afield, use `RSiteSearch()` which will send your search to [R site search](http://search.r-project.org/). As well as CRAN packages, this covers the R-help mailing list archives, help pages, vignettes and task views.

Still no luck? Try [Rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org/). It covers more sites.

Finally, if all else fails, ask here on StackOverflow or send your question to the [R-help mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-help).

Comment: I would like to find all packages mentioning `"text mining"` in the description, how would you do this?

Answer (score 19):

I believe [crantastic.org](http://crantastic.org) is hoping to help people discover and collaboratively rate/discuss packages.  It might be of use once it gets more traffic.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of service I was looking for, and did not know existed.  Bookmarked!

Answer (score 13):

A new CRAN package is extremely helpful for this: [check out the "sos" package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sos/).

Answer (score 4):

CRAN task views (BioC uses them as well): http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/

This works well as long as you think of a package in the same way as the person writing the DESCRIPTION file.

Answer (score 3):

http://versioneye.com is a cross platform search engine for Software Libraries. R Packages are in the index, too. You can rate and comment the packages. But the coolest Feature is that you can follow your packages, and as soon the next version is released you will get notified via E-Mail.

There is a "Lucky" Button, too. Similar to Google. It let you discover new packages. More Features for discovering and comparing packages are coming soon.

By the way. I am the CEO at VersionEye. I am always looking for feedback to improve the service.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to add a disclaimer that you are the CEO of this startup ... I do think the post is appropriate, and the project is interesting, but without the disclaimer it seems a little spammy.

Comment: I am sorry for that. It is true. I am the CEO. My purpose is not to create spam. VersionEye is mostly used by Java, Ruby and JavaScript developers. But I think that could be helpful for the R community, too. I am always looking for feedback to improve the service.

Comment: If you edit your question to indicate this, I would upvote it ...

Answer (score 2):

There is new service for searching through documentation of all packages [hosted on Inside-R: http://www.inside-r.org/packages](http://www.inside-r.org/packages).

Examples:

- [Neural networks](http://www.inside-r.org/search/node/neural%20network%20type%3acran_package)
- [Violin plot](http://www.inside-r.org/search/node/violin%20plot%20type%3acran_package)

*[Via Revolutions Blog](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2011/04/how-to-search-the-documentation-of-all-cran-packages.html)*

Answer (score 1):

I think you might already know this one (never assume !), but I use http://www.rseek.org/ quite a lot for this kind of issue, generally I'll try to pick out some unique keywords for my task and search here...