# Searching for packages in Python

Tags: python, search, package

Short question:

Is there some kind of package searcher for Python? Suppose you want to know what package you need to install to get specific functionality. If you're using R, you have [cranstatic](http://crantastic.org/) and even [help.search()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1417525/460147) looks very useful. What do you do to get similar perks in Python?

Comment: do you mean https://pypi.python.org/pypi

Comment: Well, I was looking for something with better searching capabilities. It doesn't seem like pypi.python.org/pypi is inspecting the documentation of each package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching https://crate.io/ for python packages.

Comment: That's what I had in mind but it seems incomplete and doesn't search the documentation.