# Where can I find useful R tutorials with various implementations?

Tags: r, implementation, r-faq

I'm using [**R**](http://www.r-project.org/) language and the manuals on the R site are really informative. However, I'd like to see some more examples and implementations with R which can help me develop my knowledge faster. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's the R book by Crawley and a whole series of "Use R!" books published by Springer, e.g. Cook and Swayne "Interactive and Dynamic Graphics for Data Analysis." Because R has been recognised in a variety of fields by researchers who need it to do statistical work, you will find quite a selection of texts.

Comment: See this other SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102056/how-to-search-for-r-materials on ways to find help with R.

Comment: Perhaps we should make this a community wiki so as to compile a "master list"?

Comment: @Sharpie: Absolutely! It's wiki now.

Comment: If you are overwhelmed by the tons of suggestions below then you can try https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-r to find the great R tutorials submitted and voted by the programming community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll mention a few that i think are excellent resources but that i haven't seen mentioned on SO. They are all free and freely available on the Web (links supplied).

***[Data Analysis Examples](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/dae/)***
A collection of individual examples from the UCLA Statistics Dept. which you can browse by major category (e.g., "Count Models", "Multivariate Analysis", "Power Analysis") then download examples with complete R code under any of these rubrics (e.g., under "Count Models" are "Poisson Regression", "Negative Binomial Regression", and so on).

***[Verzani: SimpleR: Using R for Introductory Statistics](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Verzani-SimpleR.pdf)***  A little over 100 pages, and just outstanding. It's easy to follow but very dense. It is a few years old, still i've only found one deprecated function in this text. This is a resource for a brand new R user; it also happens to be an excellent statistics refresher. This text probably contains 20+ examples (with R code and explanation) directed to fundamental statistics (e.g., hypothesis testing, linear regression, simple simulation, and descriptive statistics).

***[Statistics with R](http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/all.html)***   (Vincent Zoonekynd)  You can read it online or print it as a pdf. Printed it's well over 1000 pages. The author obviously got a lot of the information by reading the source code for the various functions he discusses--a lot of the information here, i haven't found in any other source. This resource contains large sections on Graphics, Basic Statistics, Regression, Time Series--all w/ small examples (R code + explanation). The final three sections contain the most exemplary code--very thorough application sections on Finance (which seems to be the author's professional field), Genetics, and Image Analysis.

Comment: Statistics with R is really a chest full of treasures! Highly recommended!

Answer (score 9):

Just to add some more

[Programming in R](http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/02.html)

[INTRODUCTION TO STATISTICAL MODELLING IN R](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~pat/redwsheets.pdf)

[Linear algebra in R](http://gbi.agrsci.dk/statistics/courses/mixed07/block2material/LinearAlgebraR-Handout.pdf)

[The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

[R by example](http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/index.html)

[The R Clinic](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RClinic)

[Survey analysis in R](http://faculty.washington.edu/tlumley/survey/)

[R & Bioconductor Manual](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/R_BioCondManual)

[Rtips](http://pj.freefaculty.org/R/Rtips.html)

[Resources to help you learn and use R](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/R/)

[General R Links](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/r-resources/)

Answer (score 4):

All [the packages on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/) are open source, so you can download all the source code from there. I recommend starting there by looking at the packages you use regularly to see how they're implemented.

Beyond that, [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:R) has many R examples.  And you may want to follow [R-Bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/).

Answer (score 2):

### **Book like tutorials**

Book like tutorials are usually spread in the form of PDF. Many of them are available on the R-project homepage here:

http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html#english

(This link includes many of the texts others have mentioned)

### **Article like tutorials**

These are usually present inside blogs. The biggest list of R-bloggers I know of exists here:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/

And many of these bloggers posts (many of which are tutorials) are listed here:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/archive/

(although inside each blog there are usually more tutorials).