# I want to load data in R

Tags: r, parsing

I am using `readLines("file.txt")` to read in R. I'm getting a character vector:

```
[1]"classLabel|UserName|2|1.857|Subejct|User Questio(text)n?|Answer(text).|text"
```

but I wanted to further process it as so i can have it as a dataframe

```
col1       col2      col3  col4  col5    col6     col7    col8
classLabel  usrName    2  1.857  Subject User Q   Answer   text
```

The file format is | delimited and there are 8 attributes.

```
classLabel|UserName|2|1.857|Subejct|User Questio(text)n?|Answer(text).|text
```

Also if you can share some tutorials or resources for loading Data in R would be really helpful

Comment: You might have better luck with questions like this on a sister site http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoshuaEnfield This question seems more appropriate for SO than the stats stack exchange site.  There is nothing about this question that has to do with stats other than they are using R which is primarily for statistics.

Comment: @JoshuaEnfield - for what it's worth, there's actually a very strong R support presence here on SO. I've asked a few questions and have always gotten quick, comprehensive replies. Its something that probably should be marketed to the R community a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

You may try `read.table`

`read.table("file.txt",sep="|")`

Answer (score 3):

Like lokheart said, you'll want to use `read.table`. The documentation is pretty good... type `?read.table` at the R command prompt to see help, there are examples at the end.

As for tutorials, there are a number of tutorials available online. You should check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2266200/168775) for some excellent links, as well as the [official R language introduction](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html) on the R website.

Comment: Thanks guys finally able to load the data using read.table and other parameters data<-read.table("fileName.dat",sep="|",header=FALSE,quote="",na.strings = "NA", colClasses = NA, nrows =-1,fill=TRUE,flush=TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

In R are several ways to load datasets in `csv` format, `txt` format or others formats, one way is using `read.table` for that you do the follow code:

`setwd("Directorypath")` `##remember use "//" if you are using a Windows OS`

Will be something like that your directory path:

```
"C:\\firstfolder\\secondfolder"
```

If your database has a header, you can use the follow parameters to import your dataset:

```
dataset <- read.table("FileName", sep=",", header=T)
```

However, as I said, there are a bynch ways to import data in R. 
Another exemple is using `read.csv`

```
read.csv("FileName", sep=",", header=T)
```

Or use the `readxl` package to read Excel files:

```
read_excel("FileName", sheet="nameofsheet")
```

Although, the last way take more time to load as increase your database size, being recommended you use csv formats to process your data.