# grid arrange to place table and graph on one image

Tags: r

I like to place a table and a plot in the same image. I am doing this:

my data frame x is this:

```
1/1/2010 10
1/2/2010 20
1/3/2010 15
1/4/2010 56
1/5/2010 46
1/6/2010 15
1/8/2010 15
1/9/2010 15
1/10/2010 20
1/11/2010 15
1/12/2010 15
1/13/2010 40
1/14/2010 15
1/15/2010 15
1/16/2010 70

p1<-plot(x)
p2<-tableGrob(x)

png("image1.png")
grid.arrange(p2, p1, main="Total Data and Image"
dev.off()
```

It works, but there seems to be a lot of space between p2 and p1. How can I have no or just little bit of space? Also, is there a way to make the font bigger on main?

thanks,

Comment: your code is not reproducible, what plotting package are you using?

Comment: data is not important, it could be anything. I am trying to show data in table and plot format in the same image. Space between grids are huge. I am using library(gridExtra)

Comment: @SeanKaplan: It is helpful to have a reproducible example so others can  understand what you mean by "a lot of space between p2 and p1".  It will help focus the discussion.

Comment: I think I found a work around. There may be other solutions but I thinks this works for me. thanks again.

    grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p2, p1, main="Total Data and Image", clip=TRUE, widths=c(1,2), heights=c(1,2)))

Comment: this last line is rather absurd; anyway, knowing the plotting package is important if you want an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer.

Your code is not reproducible. Wrapping your data in a `read.table()` function (and accepting default variable names), guessing that you are using base graphics, fixing typos in your code, and loading the `gridExtra` package (necessary for the `grid.arrange` function), I still cannot get your code to work. Using the `ggplot2` package to draw the graph, I can get your code to work. The code is now reproducibe. [See here for how to make a **great** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). And using my code, the result in my opinion looks pretty good. But it might not be what you intended. That's why the community asks you to generate a reproducible example. All the better then to see what you mean by "a lot of space between p2 and p1".

But taking your workaround from your comment above - there are unnecessary elements in the code. You do not need both `grid.arrange` and `arrangeGrob`. Also, because you have the elements arranged side-by-side, I don't think you need both `widths` and `heights`; `widths` alone is sufficient.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

x = read.table(text = "
1/1/2010 10
1/2/2010 20
1/3/2010 15
1/4/2010 56
1/5/2010 46
1/6/2010 15
1/8/2010 15
1/9/2010 15
1/10/2010 20
1/11/2010 15
1/12/2010 15
1/13/2010 40
1/14/2010 15
1/15/2010 15
1/16/2010 70", sep = "", header = FALSE)

p1<-ggplot(x, aes(V2, V1)) + geom_point()
p2<-tableGrob(x)
grid.arrange(p2, p1, main="Total Data and Image", ncol = 2)
```

Your fix:

```
grid.arrange(p2, p1, main="Total Data and Image", ncol = 2, widths=c(1,2))
```

**Edit**
Baptiste's solution - see comments below:

```
  grid.arrange(p2, p1, main=textGrob("Total Data and Image", gp=gpar(cex=3)), ncol = 2,
   widths=unit.c(grobWidth(p2), unit(1,"npc") - grobWidth(p2)))
```

Comment: +1 Easier yet, `grid.arrange(left=p2, p1, main=textGrob("Total Data and Image", gp=gpar(cex=3)))` since `tableGrob` has an absolute width. The title wouldn't be centered anymore though, but that gives the idea to define the widths as `unit.c(grobWidth(p2), unit(1,"npc") - grobWidth(p2))`

Answer (score 0):

To increase the font size on main use:

```
plot(x, y , cex.main=3)
```

Have a look at this post and you'll idea about the font sizes:
[Plotting in R software, how to magnify axis values in a large PNG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677788/plotting-in-r-software-how-to-magnify-axis-values-in-a-large-png-file)