# How to lower main title in gridExtra's grid.arrange?

Tags: r, margin, title, gridextra

I created a diagram using gridExtra's grid.arrange and tried to add a Main title for the entire plot before saving it to a .png file.

Using the `main="TITLE"` argument works but it is flushed with the top border, regardless of the height I set the diagram.

**My question: how do I set it such that the main title is not flushed with the top border?** One way would be to add an overall margin to the entire diagram, but again, I could not figure out how.

As an example, I modified SandyMuspratt and Baptiste's code from [grid arrange to place table and graph on one image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708315/grid-arrange-to-place-table-and-graph-on-one-image):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

x = read.table(text = "
               1/1/2010 10
               1/2/2010 20
               1/3/2010 15
               1/4/2010 56
               1/5/2010 46
               1/6/2010 15
               1/8/2010 15
               1/9/2010 15
               1/10/2010 20
               1/11/2010 15
               1/12/2010 15
               1/13/2010 40
               1/14/2010 15
               1/15/2010 15
               1/16/2010 70", sep = "", header = FALSE)

p1<-ggplot(x, aes(V2, V1)) + geom_point()
p2<-tableGrob(x)

png( filename = "TEST.png", width = 1700, height = 900, units = "px")
grid.arrange(p2, p1, main=textGrob("Total Data and Image", gp=gpar(cex=3)), 
             ncol = 2,widths=unit.c(grobWidth(p2), unit(1,"npc") - grobWidth(p2)))
dev.off()
```

The PNG output to show title flushed with border:
[image: PNG Output]

I suspect the solution could be rather simple but I can't seem to find a solution online. I have read ?grid.arrange, [Adding text to a grid.table plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774703/adding-text-to-a-grid-table-plot) and other posts, but none mentioned this.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`?textGrob` gives a hint:

```
main=textGrob("Total Data and Image", gp=gpar(cex=3), just="top")
```

**Edit** (16/07/2015): with `gridExtra` >= 2.0.0, the `main` parameter has been renamed `top`. See `?arrangeGrob` for details.

Comment: Thanks, @tonytonov! So I HAVE been looking at the wrong place for the answer after all! If I may modify your answer a bit, using `vjust=0.7` instead of `just="top"` would have placed the title right smack in the middle of the vertical space.

Comment: How to increase the space on top of the title with the outer margin of the document? I tried pat() unsuccessfully.