# How can I visualize a data.frame with a values column and a label column in R?

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I'm using the `pdf` command and `ggplot2` to create couple different types of graphs and while I'm at it I'd like to throw in some simple tables (with, for example, column labels being coefficient names and rows having values) but I'm not sure to make a "plot" out of that without going separately into excel to make a table (but then I don't know how to insert it into the pdf I generate with R)

For example suppose I've got a `data.frame` like this one:

```
set.seed(1)
foo = data.frame(val1=rnorm(5), val2=rnorm(5), columnLabels=c('A','B','C','D','F'))
```

Is there a simple way to "plot" a simple table with those column labels, with row labels like c('Val 1', 'Val2') and with the corresponding values?

Comment: look into the package `knitr`, specifically the function `kable`, or the package `xtable`

Comment: I use the `textplot()` function in the package 'gplots' to do this.

Comment: @ulfelder textplot is working, wonder if there's a way to add it to the grid.arrange for ggplot2 plots?

Comment: Good question to which I don't know the answer.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708315/) what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tableGrob() function in GridExtra may help.

```
> library(grid)
> library(gridExtra)

> set.seed(1)
> d = data.frame(val1=rnorm(5), val2=rnorm(5), columnLabels=c('A','B','C','D','F'))

> # transpose dataframe to get requested columns/rows
> rownames(d) <- d$columnLabels
> d$columnLabels <- NULL
> dt <- t(d)

> g <- tableGrob(dt)
> grid.newpage()
> grid.draw(g)
```

Which is basically

```
> example(tableGrob)
```