# Plotting to a file in R

Tags: r

I'm a complete newbie to R, and none of the introductions I've seen cover how to use R when all you've got is the command line and no windowing system. My data's on a server, and I'm working with it via ssh. In gnuplot, you can set your "display" to be a PNG file on disk. How do I plot something to a file on disk from R? R-2.9.1 on CentOS, if it matters. Thanks!

(Sorry if this is unusually basic, but I have the worst time Googling for quick answers with R. Cute name, impossible to search for.)

Comment: Use http://rseek.org which constrains Google search to relevant sites and adds a few more bells and whistles.

Comment: Googling for anything to do with R is a classic problem :) You might find http://www.rseek.org useful, or there are many other suggestions in answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102056/how-to-search-for-r-materials

Comment: Excellent, on the searching problem. Thanks, guys. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that `postscrpt()`, `pdf()`, `png()`, and `jpeg()` have specific function parameters which can be used to customize the output.

For example:

```
postscript("filename.eps", horizontal=F, width=4, height=4, 
             paper="special", onefile=F)
plot(x)
dev.off()
```

check `?postscript`for more information on the parameters that can be utilized.

Secondly, keep in mind that all commands that you want to be included in your saved plot should be executed prior to `dev.off()`

For example:

```
postscript("filename.eps", horizontal=F, width=4, height=4, 
             paper="special", onefile=F)
plot(x)    
text(5, 1, "This is a message for the aliens")
text(5, 0.5, "Pizza is tasty")
dev.off()
```

Another example:

```
regone <- glm(y ~ x1, data=mydata, family=...)
summary(regone)

postscript("filename.eps", horizontal=F, width=4, height=4, 
                 paper="special", onefile=F)
plot(x, y)
abline(regone)
dev.off()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah; even better examples, with some handy tips. Thanks a bunch! (Now of course I need to get some friendly admin to actually put the device drivers in place on our server.)

Answer (score 9):

Just to expand on Gnoupi answer, you also need to close the connection to the device with `dev.off` if you want the plot to be written to file.

For instance

```
pdf("mygraph.pdf")
plot(x, y, "l")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Ah. An actual example of device usage was just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for giving an example, I only quoted the manual, didn't know how to use it.

Comment: You should note that there is `png(...)`, too.

Answer (score 3):

From their documentation, it seems you have to use [device drivers](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Device-drivers):

> R can generate graphics (of varying
>   levels of quality) on almost any type
>   of display or printing device. Before
>   this can begin, however, R needs to be
>   informed what type of device it is
>   dealing with. This is done by starting
>   a device driver. The purpose of a
>   device driver is to convert graphical
>   instructions from R (“draw a line,”
>   for example) into a form that the
>   particular device can understand.
>
> (...)
>
> - postscript() - For printing on PostScript printers, or creating
>     PostScript graphics files.
> - pdf() - Produces a PDF file, which can also be included into PDF files.
> - png() - Produces a bitmap PNG file. (Not always available: see its help
>     page.)
> - jpeg() - Produces a bitmap JPEG file, best used for image plots. (Not
>     always available: see its help page.)

Comment: Remember to close the file with dev.off()! If you don't use dev.off(), the file will be created but never written to, and you'll get an error.

Answer (score 2):

If your connection to the server is fast enough, you could try X11 forwarding through your ssh connection - basically the server will plot to a window on your local screen, quite useful!

[HOWTO no 1](http://solaris.reys.net/how-to-x11-forwarding-using-ssh-putty-and-xming/)

[HOWTO no 2](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html)

Comment: Yeah, not what I need; but handy links for other situations. Thanks!