# How does one searches efficiently the internet for [R,the statistical package] related questions?

Tags: search, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search for “R” materials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102056/how-to-search-for-r-materials)

Dear all,
I have recently picked up the task of programming in R.
R is the statistical package / programming enviroment/language.

But there is horror! Because searching for R related questions
in, say, google will yield a lot of irrelevant matches simply because
'R' is, well, such a common thing a document to contain...

e.g. 
R non-parametric distribution fit

Question: Is there a better way to search for R questions in google and other search engines?

thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102056/how-to-search-for-r-materials

Comment: mea culpa feel free to vote to close it.

Comment: "But there is horror!" is possibly one of the best statements I have ever seen on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Rseek](http://www.rseek.org).  You can find other search methods by clicking on the [Search](http://www.r-project.org/search.html) link on the R-project homepage.

Answer (score 1):

see if this gives you a better resultset.. non-parametric distribution fit +"R"

Comment: On average, "+R" as a search term has yielded the best results on my Google searches.