# How do a perform a weighted, 2d kernel density estimation in R?

Tags: r, kernel-density

I would like to produce a kernel density estimation in R, and am somewhat bamboozled by all the different packages.  I need to be able to:

1. Specify weights
2. Specify bandwidth size
3. Specify bin size

How would you go about this?   Bonus points for a code snippet.

Comment: Try on http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you looked at the Spatial task view? http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html

Answer (score 3):

See also the [ks package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ks/index.html)
and the nice picture in
[Multivariate kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_kernel_density_estimation).

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are a number of packages. You should first decide **which** 2D kernel estimate you want. In the fields package you have a function smooth.2d, and you have the wonderful package of Brian Ripley, KernSmooth. The extra points for the code snippets you can give to the help files, I ain't going to copy them.

For these kind of questions, also try [www.rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org).

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I'm very much new to the R world and its culture, and its taking a while to learn how things are done here :)

Comment: @fmark: no problem. You can also take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102056/how-to-search-for-r-materials and this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192369/books-for-learning-the-r-language

Comment: In answer to your question, a Gaussian smoother will do me nicely, and the `fields` package `smooth.2d` seems to have all the parameters I require.