# r select column element based on condition

Tags: r, select

```
> w
                 A           B
1998-01-08 -0.0051653999  0.007
1998-01-09  0.0064191599 -0.008
1998-01-12 -0.0018169993  0.009
1998-01-13  0.0046482541 -0.005
1998-01-14  0.0080997329 -0.006
1998-01-15 -0.0007764179  0.008

c<-(-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,0.1,0.2,0.3)
```

I want to create a matrix with one column that selects A or B from w conditional on whether c > 0

i.e.

```
w[,if (c<0) A else B]
                 C           
1998-01-08 -0.0051653999
1998-01-09  0.0064191599
1998-01-12 -0.0018169993
1998-01-13 -0.005
1998-01-14 -0.006
1998-01-15  0.008
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `c` function for concatenating the vector `(-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,0.1,0.2,0.3)`, I used `ind` as the name for that vector. Then indexing can be done using `ifelse` function as in:

```
> ind <-c(-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,0.1,0.2,0.3)
> data.frame(C=ifelse(ind<0, w$A, w$B), row.names=rownames(w))
                      C
1998-01-08 -0.005165400
1998-01-09  0.006419160
1998-01-12 -0.001816999
1998-01-13 -0.005000000
1998-01-14 -0.006000000
1998-01-15  0.008000000
```

Comment: That's great thank you. For me row.name didn't work -but not really an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this [Extract matrix column values by matrix column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744694/r-extract-matrix-column-values-by-matrix-column-name)
In short, I think you want to try this command:
if(c<0)
w[,"A"]
else
w[,"B"]

Comment: I used 1 and 2 instead but get this error:Warning message:
In if (c <0) 1 else 2 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @ManInMoon what you got is not an error, it's a warning, from the help of `if` you'll find the following: `Conditions of length greater than one are accepted with a warning, but only the first element is used.` Use `ifelse` instead, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736232/r-select-column-element-based-on-condition/16736468#16736468).