# locate eligible element in the matrix, and extract the other element from the same row

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I gain a matrix from following program, and trying to extract the specified url from it:

```
#loading webpage and analyzing
library(XML)
community_url<-"http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/community-list"
com_source <- readLines(community_url, encoding = "UTF-8")
com_parsed <- htmlTreeParse(com_source, encoding = "UTF-8", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
hrefs <- xpathSApply(com_parsed, '//li[@class="communityLink"]//@href', function(x) unname(x))
irname <- xpathSApply(com_parsed, '//li[@class="communityLink"]//a', xmlValue)
cl_table <- cbind(hrefs, irname)
colnames(cl_table) <- c("hrefs", "h1")
```

I tried `url <- cl_table[cl_table$h1=="文献情报中心", ]`and `which(cl_table$h1=="文献情报中心")` to do it, but it cause an error:

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

and even if it works, I could not get the url of "文献情报中心"(/handle/1471x/23660), how should I do?
By the way, is there any method for both matrix and dataframe class? If we save this table and read it the class will be dataframe as default. Thanks a lot.

Comment: well, don't use the dollar operator for matrices

Comment: I had tried to use bracks instead of $, just like:`> url <- cl_table(url,)[cl_table(,h1)=="文献情报中心"]
Error: could not find function "cl_table"
> url <- cl_table[url,][cl_table[,h1]=="文献情报中心"]
Error in cl_table[url, ] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: you mean like this? `cl_table[, 'h1']`

Comment: It doesn't work even changed into `> url <- cl_table('url',)[cl_table(, 'h1')=="文献情报中心"]
Error: could not find function "cl_table"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that you are having trouble with how to select a column of a matrix by its name. You might find a helping answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744722/3871924) also.

In fact the dollar sign is OK for data.frames but not for matrices (which your data is). In your case I would do:

```
url <- cl_table[cl_table[,'h1']=="文献情报中心", 'hrefs']
print(url)
#### hrefs 
#### "/handle/1471x/23660"
```

And then, if you want to use this piece of url to open it for instance (you have to make sure that you get only one element in the `url` result of course):

```
browseURL( paste0("http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/", url[1]) )
```