# Extract matrix column with it's name

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say you have a matrix defined as

```
m1 = matrix(
  rbind(c(12,8,9),c(4100,3600,3200)), 
  byrow=FALSE, 
  nrow=2, 
  ncol=3, 
  dimnames=list(c("Days","Amount"),c("Col1","Col2","Col3"))
  )
```

Which yields:

```
       Col1 Col2 Col3
Days     12    8    9
Amount 4100 3600 3200
```

And you need to show (knowing the position of the column, here 3) name of the column and its values, so that you have information about the parameters like:

```
  Days Amount 
     9   3200
```

But you also need to know the column name which carries some real information about its values (ie hotel name).

The above you could achieve with `m1[, 3]` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744694/extract-matrix-column-values-by-matrix-column-name), but **how does one print it together with the column header?** (here "Col3")

Comment: just `m1[,'Col3',drop=FALSE]`

Comment: related: [*Extract matrix column values by matrix column name*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744694/r-extract-matrix-column-values-by-matrix-column-name)

Comment: @Jaap is it really a duplicate? I want to extract column name alongside its values. Linked question and answers do not present a solution for that. I've reviewed your linked question before posting.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. Please visit the linked target. It is a different than the one I posted in my comment above.

Comment: @Jaap you're right. Question was really hard to find though due to it's title... I didn't stumble upon that while searching which either means I do not know how to name it or it isn't straightforward.

Comment: @KamilG If you have any other questions, you have the option to edit the post and update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `drop = FALSE` without converting to `data.frame`

```
m1[,3, drop = FALSE]
#        Col3
#Days      9
#Amount 3200
```

Comment: Even better and faster thanks.

Comment: Can't find any documentation on this option. Could you please put a reference link?

Comment: @KamilG.  You can find it in `?Extract`

Answer (score 1):

You could coerce `m1` to `data.frame` and slice the required column

```
as.data.frame(m1)[3]
#OR
as.data.frame(m1)["Col3"]
#       Col3
#Days      9
#Amount 3200
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't occur to me to use data frames. Great and fast answer.