# Drop columns by name data frame vs matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I want to drop columns by name in a matrix, I noticed that it does not work the same as for data frame:

```
df <- as.matrix(data.frame(x=1:5, y=2:6, z=3:7, u=4:8))

df[ , -which(names(df) %in% c("z","u"))]


df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=2:6, z=3:7, u=4:8)

df[ , -which(names(df) %in% c("z","u"))]
```

Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: Use `colnames` instead of `names` when you have a matrix

Comment: Why this difference?

Comment: Because matrices and data frames are different. Columns aren't as special in matrices as they are in data frames. `colnames` will work for both.

Comment: `data.frame` is essentially `list` with properties of matrix in R. You can't expect matrix to be having every method same as `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a matrix you can use `colnames` or `rownames` (or, if you need to generalize up to an array with more dimensions, the `dimnames` list).

`names` isn't defined for a matrix. It is defined for a `list`, and thus for a `data.frame`, where columns are generally *more important* (in some sense, at least), so it is a safe convention that `names` refers to column names. But in an array there is no reason to prefer one dimension to another.

A similar question is [Extract matrix column values by matrix column name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5744694/903061).