# reference a column in a xgb.DMatrix for model prediction

Tags: r, matrix, prediction, xgboost

I would like to reference a column in a xgb.DMatrix and use it in an if condition.
Is it possible to reference elements in a column in an xgb.DMatrix? (I am using the `xgboost` package)

Such as:

```
mat1_xgb[date_created<latest_date,]
```

where

```
 latest_date is some date in numeric format
 mat1_xgb$date_created is a column of dates in numeric formats
```

**Example**

In r code:

```
Matrix_1:
| date_created | val1 | date_closed |
|  17912       |2.3   |  17914      |
| 17913        |2.  5 |  17915      |
| 17932        |2.1   |  17941      |
```

Then create a for loop where the xgboost model is run using only the dates prior to an increment date:

```
for(i in seq(2,dim(Matrix_1)[1],1)){

   latest_date = Matrix_1[2,date_created]
   xgb1_learn = xgboost(data = Matrix_1[date_closed<latest_date], params = params, etc)
   data_table_1[i:i+50] = predict(xgb1_learn, Matrix_1[i:i+50])
}
```

So we train the model only on past datapoints

Comment: Not clear without a reproducible example.  Can you show a small example?  Also specify the packages used

Comment: package used was Xgboost

Comment: my question relates to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744694/extract-matrix-column-values-by-matrix-column-name) but with xgb.DMatrix

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?