# How to specify the actual x axis values to plot as x axis ticks in R

Tags: r, plot

I am creating a plot in R and I dont like the x axis values being plotted by R.

For example:

```
x <- seq(10,200,10)
y <- runif(x)

plot(x,y)
```

This plots a graph with the following values on the X axis:

`50, 100, 150, 200`

However, I want to plot the 20 values `10,20, 30 ... 200` stored in variable x, as the X axis values. I have scoured through countless blogs and the terse manual - after hours of searching, the closest I've come to finding anything useful is the following (summarized) instructions:

1. call `plot()` or `par()`, specifying argument `xaxt='n'`
2. call `axis()` e.g. `axis(side = 1, at = seq(0, 10, by = 0.1), labels = FALSE, tcl = -0.2)`

I tried it and the resulting plot had no x axis values at all. Is it possible that someone out there knows how to do this? I can't believe that no one has ever tried to do this before.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You'll find the answer to your question in the help page for `?axis`.

Here is one of the help page examples, modified with your data:

Option 1: use `xaxp` to define the axis labels

```
plot(x,y, xaxt="n")
axis(1, xaxp=c(10, 200, 19), las=2)
```

Option 2: Use `at` and `seq()` to define the labels:

```
plot(x,y, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at = seq(10, 200, by = 10), las=2)
```

Both these options yield the same graphic:

[image]

---

PS. Since you have a large number of labels, you'll have to use additional arguments to get the text to fit in the plot.  I use `las` to rotate the labels.

Answer (score 8):

Hope this coding will helps you :)

```
plot(x,y,xaxt = 'n')

axis(side=1,at=c(1,20,30,50),labels=c("1975","1980","1985","1990"))
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a closer look at the `?axis` documentation. If you look at the description of the `labels` argument, you'll see that it is:

```
"a logical value specifying whether (numerical) annotations are 
to be made at the tickmarks,"
```

So, just change it to true, and you'll get your tick labels.

```
x <- seq(10,200,10)
y <- runif(x)
plot(x,y,xaxt='n')
axis(side = 1, at = x,labels = T)
# Since TRUE is the default for labels, you can just use axis(side=1,at=x)
```

Be careful that if you don't stretch your window width, then R might not be able to write all your labels in. Play with the window width and you'll see what I mean.

---

It's too bad that you had such trouble finding documentation! What were your search terms? Try typing `r axis` into Google, and the first link you will get is that [Quick R page that I mentioned earlier](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html). Scroll down to "Axes", and you'll get a very nice little guide on how to do it. You should probably check there first for any plotting questions, it will be faster than waiting for a SO reply.

Comment: Careful. `T` doesn't always to `TRUE`. Better to specify `labels = TRUE`. Also, google search results will depend on your search history.  For tips on how to search for [tag:r] , see [how-to-search-for-r-materials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102056/how-to-search-for-r-materials)

Answer (score 1):

In case of plotting time series, the command `ts.plot` requires a different argument than `xaxt="n"`

```
require(graphics)
ts.plot(ldeaths, mdeaths, xlab="year", ylab="deaths", lty=c(1:2), gpars=list(xaxt="n"))
axis(1, at = seq(1974, 1980, by = 2))
```