# Set the number of divisions on plotting axes

Tags: r

In R, I'm wondering how I can set the number of divisions on the plotting axes (x or y). The default way of division in R looks sometimes very sparse.

Specifically, is there a way to only increase the number of tickmarks (say * 10 with more granularity) without increasing the occurrence of numeric values on the axis (otherwise to crowded)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen `?axis` for manually adding an axis to a plot?

Comment: If you mean how to describe the axis ticks have a look a this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775692/how-to-specify-the-actual-x-axis-values-to-plot-as-x-axis-ticks-in-r)