# How to increase plot label size without losing label values in R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to increase label size by modifying the `cex.axis` option:

```
plot(0~0, type="n", xlim=range(int), ylim=c(0,max.of.range), xlab="Dist. from TSS", ylab="Seq Counts", cex.lab=4, cex.axis=4.5, cex.main=2, main=paste0("Combined Average Plot for ", sample.name, " timepoints (", name.of.genelist, ")"))
```

but as you can see, I lose certain numbers in the sequence of the label values. How can I retain all the numbers? Or how can I manually set which label values to keep?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify the actual x axis values to plot as x axis ticks in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775692/how-to-specify-the-actual-x-axis-values-to-plot-as-x-axis-ticks-in-r)

Comment: Increase the size of the plot when printing in file.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating the labels would probably work. Look into the `las` or `srt` parameters.

For example:

```
plot(0~0, type="n", ... srt="45")
```