# How to change the x-axis labels from a character to a different one?

Tags: r, plot, axis, axis-labels

I've got a questions regarding the xaxis labels.
In contrast to whats discussed in here:

[How to specify the actual x axis values to plot as x axis ticks in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775692/how-to-specify-the-actual-x-axis-values-to-plot-as-x-axis-ticks-in-r)

I plotted a dataframe containing 10 columns. Each one is represented in a boxplot.
For the x-axis my labels are Pipe1 till Pipe 10. Now I wanna change those labels to a specific ID for instance this way

```
windows()
par(mfrow= c(2,1),las=3)
boxplot(output.valid.fast,outline=F, xlab ="Pipes",ylab="RMSE(-)")
axis(1,at=c("Pipe1","Pipe2","Pipe3","Pipe4","Pipe5","Pipe6","Pipe7","Pipe8","Pipe9","Pipe10"),labels=c("1234","2345","3456","4567","5678","6789","78910","891011","9101112","10111213"))
```

everytime I'm doing so, I receive an error revealing the following:

```
In axis(1, at = c("Pipe1", "Pipe2", "Pipe3", "Pipe4", "Pipe5", "Pipe6",  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

What did I do wrong in here? I'd highly appreciate hints or advices.
Cheers,
Olli

Comment: thanks a lot, that was it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `at = c("Pipe1", ... , "Pipe10")` by `at = 1:10`.

#### Example with 2 columns

```
boxplot(data.frame(Pipe1 = 1:10, Pipe2 = 2:11), xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = 1:2, labels = c("1234","2345"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on Djacks answer to explain what is happening, R is plotting an axis on a numerical scale, and then applying the labels *pipe 1* etc. to those by default. You need to first suppress the default text labels using `xaxt = "n"` in your boxplot function (notice at this point that it is still producing the plot with an unlabelled x-axis) and then tell it to apply your chosen labels at the chosen locations using `labels` and `at` respectively in the `axis` function, with `at = 1:10`.

Further illustrating this point that the axes are using a numerical coordinate system, you could plot text on the plot in line with the 3rd box using `text("abc", x = 3, y = 0)`.