# Density plot - how to change frequency on x-axis

Tags: r, density-plot

I created the below code to generate a density plot, however the frequency of the x axis is way too big ie it counts in 2's. However the value of most of my data is less that 1 so I want to be able to change the frequency of the x axis. Is that possible?

```
my_density_plot <- data.frame(Data = Data)
b <- ggplot(my_density_plot, aes(x=Data))+ labs(title = "Density test", y = 
"Density")
b <- b + stat_density(geom = "line", alpha = 1, colour = "cornflowerblue")
print(b)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify the actual x axis values to plot as x axis ticks in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775692/how-to-specify-the-actual-x-axis-values-to-plot-as-x-axis-ticks-in-r)

Comment: Welcome to SO!Please, provide your data, or an example of them, using maybe `dput()`, to make reproducible your example.

Answer (score 1):

Add a line:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(#'s, you, want), labels = c(labels, you, want))
```

Check out the documentation at https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html