# R - Base Plot Function - Customize Axis

Tags: r, plot

I am using the plot function from Base R to display years on X axis and loan amount on Y axis.

Type of Year variable is double and so is the type of loan amount.

When I plot it, the X axis display values like 2018... 2018.5 .... 2019 ... 2019.5

How to fix this so that the X axis doesn't display decimal values of the year.

Thank You.

Comment: Convert the x-axis column as factor.

Comment: check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775692/how-to-specify-the-actual-x-axis-values-to-plot-as-x-axis-ticks-in-r

Comment: I liked the xaxp parameter. It worked. thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify the actual x axis values to plot as x axis ticks in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775692/how-to-specify-the-actual-x-axis-values-to-plot-as-x-axis-ticks-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to convert the x-axis value as factor. For example :

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(4), year = 2005:2008)
plot(x~year, df)

df$year <- factor(df$year)
plot(x~year, df)
```