# Searching for Documentation In R

Tags: r

I would like to create a vector that is spaced by .5 from 1 to 10. So 1 1.5 2 2.5 .... 9.5 10. How do I that in R?

Now what if I want to create a vector from 1 to 10 , equally spaced, that has a length of 20 how do I do that?

Lastly, is there an easier way to search documentation in R, such as typing "equally spaced" or "vector of fixed length" to find out what codes are availiable? So far CRAN's documentation is for those who know the function first and can easily search it. The search engine doesn't allow searching words in the documentation that might lead to the relevant function.

Comment: `seq()` should do what you want. Also, R allows for "fuzzy matching" via the `??` command. In your R terminal, type `??"equally spaced"` to see if anything comes up. Also, see R package SOS for other search facilities: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sos/index.html

Comment: The 13th most [highly voted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/102056/324364) R question on StackOverflow.

Comment: You're looking for a sequence. A fuzzy search for `??sequence` should help you find that function (`seq`) in no time since it does say "Sequence generation" in the description. That or search on SO under the r tag.

Comment: The "sos" package is nice for finding functions of interest.

Comment: The [introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Generating-regular-sequences) has a section devoted entirely to this

Answer (score 2):

I'm only demonstrating what has already been suggested: use `seq`.

```
seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 0.5)
#  [1]  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0  5.5  6.0  6.5  7.0  7.5  8.0
# [16]  8.5  9.0  9.5 10.0

seq(from = 1, to = 10, length.out = 20)
#  [1]  1.000000  1.473684  1.947368  2.421053  2.894737  3.368421  3.842105
#  [8]  4.315789  4.789474  5.263158  5.736842  6.210526  6.684211  7.157895
# [15]  7.631579  8.105263  8.578947  9.052632  9.526316 10.000000
```

And yes, `??sequence` is one way you could have found about `seq`. When you don't have the right keyword(s), forums or places like here are always a good place.